# Changing col-xs-12 to col-md-6 color responsive

Tags: responsive-design, pug, bootstrapping, stylus

I have a container broken down into two `col-md-6` of different colors.

Let's say one is green the other is yellow.

I am trying to transform these two columns into one `col-xs-12` with a gradient color going from, as you expected green -> yellow.

Jade:

```
.container-six
 .row
  .col-xs-12.col-md-6.left
  .col-md-6.right
```

Stylus:

```
.container-six
 height: 150px
 background-color: white
 .row
  height:100%
  .col-xs-12
   height  150px
   background: linear-gradient(to left,#ff8533,#99ccff)
  .col-xs-12.col-md-6.left
    background-color:#ff8533
  .right
    background-color:#99ccff
```

Comment: whats the actual problem. that you facing with this code.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to merge both **col-md-6** div into **col-xs-12** then remove style property and use property for main div

background: linear-gradient(to right,#92af4c,#fff707);

Comment: I was probably not accurate enough. Where I am stuck is when you say "remove style property" of the col-xs-12 so that I can give two different properties to each col-md-6.

Comment: remove styles from each col-md-6 and apply only on col-xs-12 div

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want to achieve?

[image: screenshots]

```css
/* Heart of the matter */
.row.two-colors {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( 0deg, yellow, green);
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient( 0deg, yellow, green);
  background:      -o-linear-gradient( 0deg, yellow, green);
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, yellow, green);
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row.two-colors > div:first-child {
    background: yellow;
  }
  .row.two-colors > div:last-child {
    background: green;
  }
}

/* Decorations */
.row.two-colors > div {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding-top: 6px; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row two-colors">
    <div class="col-md-6">First</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nop, I want to have for example a phone width displaying the one div with gradient left yellow to right green, which when increased to desktop width that it breaks into two divs which on left side will have yellow color and the second the green color

Comment: @alexanderjanet What happens to the contents when the block is divided into two parts?

Comment: Your code won't even allow them to divide. With my code, either the gradient will be displayed in each div, that is the col-xs-12 and then the col-md-6, or if i play around, I end up having the col-xs-12 being of the same color of the left col-md-6.

Comment: @alexanderjanet So I see you don't like my layout. But does it behave as you need?

Comment: what you are displaying above your code is exactly what I am looking for. For some reason when I paste your code it does not change from gradient to the two child divs -_-

Comment: @alexanderjanet You can try to add `!important` to the `background` property: `@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row.two-colors > div:first-child {
    background: yellow !important;
  }
  .row.two-colors > div:last-child {
    background: green !important;
  }
}`

Comment: For some reason it is not displaying any change. Just the gradient. I will come back to it later and post an answer once I get it done -_-

Comment: @alexanderjanet You can make jsfiddle or codepen. Then I'll try to help.